# How to write results from text files after computations?

Tags: r

I have three text files . I want to do some calculations as shown below and write the results. All text files contain 14 columns X1 to X14 and 601 rows. This code basically calculate the correlations between (e.g.  x1 from ref file and same column x1 from the file sour1  and so on) from all three files and do some computations and then return the results.

```
ref= read.table("D:\\S_asc.txt", sep="",header=TRUE)
sour1 = read.table("D:\\sre.txt", sep="",header=TRUE) 
sour2= read.table("D:\\os_asc.txt", sep="",header=TRUE)
columns <- paste0("X", 1:13)
lapply(
    columns,
    function(column)
    {
        result1 <- cor(ref[[column]],sour2[[column]],use = "na.or.complete")
        # calculate using ref and sour1

        result2 <-  cor(ref[[column]],sour1[[column]],use = "na.or.complete")   
        # calculate using ref and sour2

    }
)
```

I am getting error when writing the results:

```
write.table(result1,file = "foo.text")
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'result1' not found
```

sample of my file:

```
"0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" "11" "12" "13" "14"
"2" 0.189444444142282 0.317999997238318 0.166363635072202 0.301255410351666 0.471986238597248       0.307140744955515 0.411269603728529 0.262293613227113 0.265422601640182 0.196970316722191      0.123789306669182 0.291404434246697 0.322141939017999 0.43499182336885 0.327559809775301
"3" 0.149411764616768 0.191176471464774 0.180181817100807 0.422626723831494 0.496283823857852 0.327019521055943 0.441349119295007 0.286810015617714 0.24089.

        dput( head( ref ) ) 
          structure(list(X0 = c(0.0493461075417879, 0.0505162129561387, 
       0.0490028816673631, 0.049519460579677, 0.0496427079798826, 0.0506145435593228
       ), X1 = c(0.0262911450465596, 0.0249440745179165, 0.0240951294080254, 
      0.0256401352066387, 0.0258794329817874, 0.0247771567181071), 
        X2 = c(0.0426611743228151, 0.0374958657769128, 0.0306825108745032, 
         0.0393093163299325, 0.0398889994476742, 0.0435458658141826
         ), X3 = c(0.0954854469641096, 0.0833464493313783, 0.0790441582634745, 
         0.0818814458477848, 0.0772971938289144, 0.0818534809699011
        ), X4 = c(0.0933782886825547, 0.0968294484334356, 0.0981543002252867, 
         0.0969233013221434, 0.0933197039086707, 0.0913029715102785
         ), X5 = c(0.218212200747129, 0.220014530510402, 0.21109789420558, 
         0.204679954607016, 0.210967709615173, 0.20799168387628), 
       X6 = c(0.285405481705908, 0.284798691283541, 0.280772749846878, 
         0.285532926668878, 0.293501364933202, 0.296710869439616), 
        X7 = c(0.226218243796976, 0.216760771202585, 0.205519652752883, 
        0.206054283066245, 0.211842009508557, 0.214360803181363), 
       X8 = c(0.146648210899044, 0.144789395382814, 0.142059144367336, 
        0.141852209487122, 0.140823495101071, 0.140405076285803), 
        X9 = c(0.115716572518044, 0.113825119638324, 0.111749156097298, 
        0.111175507359272, 0.11094649408726, 0.111155298251533), 
         X10 = c(0.0675501818197432, 0.0636083677843573, 0.0605178392071445, 
           0.0549028963149205, 0.0600036757169919, 0.0625667586974292
         ), X11 = c(0.069120070466305, 0.0662362222295113, 0.0710726619403152, 
         0.0653345812188053, 0.0612221754441228, 0.0584222641456072
            ), X12 = c(0.281314574594234, 0.279000957729072, 0.276184085574267, 
            0.274121716868717, 0.271324697416127, 0.270268668362535), 
              X13 = c(0.364434947521643, 0.369388875815867, 0.372250445014838, 
          0.372470394613093, 0.372814994985087, 0.369151832740263), 
                X14 = c(0.0124844383491671, 0.0125512696973245, 0.0125538467586845, 
                   0.012599469429366, 0.0125682867660489, 0.0126515616426303
                   )), .Names = c("X0", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", 
                     "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "X11", "X12", "X13", "X14"), row.names = c("2", 
                     "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign result1 to lapply.i.e.

```
result1 <- lapply( columns , function(column) { cor(ref[[column]],sour2[[column]],use = "na.or.complete") } )
```

And do the same for result 2:

```
result2 <- lapply( columns , function( column ) { cor(ref[[column]],sour1[[column]],use = "na.or.complete") } )
```

To separate out your results try altering your code to format your results like this...

```
    columns <- paste0("X", 1:13)
result1 <- lapply( columns , function(column){ cor(ref[[column]],sour2[[column]],use = "na.or.complete") } )
result2 <- lapply( columns , function(column){ cor(ref[[column]],sour1[[column]],use = "na.or.complete") } )
names( result1 ) <- columns
names( result2 ) <- columns


write.table( result1 , file = "foo.txt" , row.names = "res1" )
write.table( result2 , file = "foo.txt" , row.names = "res2" , col.names = FALSE  , append = TRUE )
```

Comment: Thaks Simon.I wrote the results using the command shown above but I got that x is mix with number and weird arrangement:

Comment: @JonssonSali see the code edit at the bottom. Does this help with the second problem?

Comment: No not really.still getting the same thing.

Comment: I am not sure why. The first code sample works perfectly on my system. Can you paste the output of `dput( head( ref ) )` into your question above as a code block.

Comment: it is pasting x with value and also provides the value

Comment: Did you check again with the sample I provided?

Comment: No time yet sorry I will later. Did you check my answer to your other question?

Comment: @JonssonSali updated code. Try the code in the bottom code box to get and output your results. Should be nicely formatted.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that error because the variable created inside a function are out of scope outside that function i.e. when following function is evaluated, `R` doesn't know store values of `result1` and `result2` for use outside that function

```
function(column)
    {
        result1 <- cor(ref[[column]],sour2[[column]],use = "na.or.complete")
        # calculate using ref and sour1

        result2 <-  cor(ref[[column]],sour1[[column]],use = "na.or.complete")   
        # calculate using ref and sour2

    }
```

To demonstrate what I just said, try below code

```
testFunc <- function() {
    a <- 0
}

testFunc()

print(a)
```

You get error as follows :

```
Error in print(a) : object 'a' not found
```

Hence as suggested by `SimonO101`, you will have to assign result of `lapply` call for `sour1` and `sour2` individually.

```
result1 <- lapply( columns , function(column) { cor(ref[[column]],sour2[[column]],use = "na.or.complete") } )

result2 <- lapply( columns , function( column ) { cor(ref[[column]],sour1[[column]],use = "na.or.complete") } )
```

Comment: I used this to write the results:`write.table(result1,file = "foo.text")` but I got `"X0.934739749861472" "X0.914100405112019" "X0.904051579365356"` x is not separated from the values. I want them to follow the same order  as of the files  so X1  value , X2 value , ...etc